# Ruby Class and Object singleton - get access

Tags: ruby

I learning ruby singletons and have misunderstanding with such code:

```
class MyClass
  def self.class_singleton_mymethod
  end
end

class_singleton = class << MyClass
  self
end

puts class_singleton.methods.grep(/mymethod/)  # => []


obj = MyClass.new

def obj.object_singleton_mymethod
end

object_singleton = class << obj
  self
end

puts object_singleton.methods.grep(/mymethod/) # => class_singleton_mymethod
```

Why class_singleton **not** contains class's *Class* method and object_singleton instead of *Object's* singleton method contains class's *Class* method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the notion of `methods` and `instance_methods` mixed up. If you were to replace all instances of `methods` with `instance_methods`, you will see the results you expect.

`instance_methods` is used to enumerate which methods a class's instances have. `methods` is used to enumerate what methods the object has. (Class objects are objects too, and have their own methods like `new` that are not instance methods.

For example, `String#slice` is an instance method; you can call `slice` on string *instances*. On the other hand, `String.new` is a method on `String` itself; you don't call `new` on string instances, but you can call `String.new` (i.e., on the `String` class object itself) to create a new string.)

Comment: @Vladimir: Thanks, it took me two tries to get it right, but I'm glad to have an answer I'm happy with. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand, but are your trying to implement the Singleton Design Pattern?

Use the [Singleton Module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/index.html) it implements the tern for you, you just include it

Comment: -1 No. Singleton classes in Ruby have nothing to do with the singleton pattern.

Comment: I try to understand why `class_singleton` (that contains Sinleton object for MyClass) not have MyClass singleton method inside

Comment: He's talking about singleton classes/eigenclasses in Ruby. The name is a bit confusing, but basically, every object has a unique singleton class right below its class in the class hierarchy.

Comment: Hey i waa trying to be helpful, I said i wasnt sure, was that really the need to downvote? I somewhat understand the difference between eigenclass and Singleton pattern, at least to the point they are different, although have little knowledge of the former. Just wasn't sure what was being asked. Thats why I prefaced my answer in such a way. The terminology can confusing, I thought that this might be helpful, apparently I was wrong, my apologies.

Comment: @loosecannon: Actually, I dislike (incorrect) speculative answers, and feel they have no place in an "experts' Q&A site", so I will downvote them when I see them.

Comment: I understand your sentiments, I didn't realize this was only for experts. I am in High School and in no way an expert. Nonetheless I try to be helpful and contribute when I think I might know something.